# Рисование кольца в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток, мне нужно сделать в Unity кольцо (как компонент UI) , которое со временем будет уменьшаться, то есть каждый момент времени из кольца будет сектор вырезаться. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `Canvas` есть компонент `Image`, у которого можно в качестве источника указать спрайт (то есть у любой картинки просто задать *TextureType* → *Sprite (2D and UI)*).

Далее...У этого компонента (Image) есть настраиваемые поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если установить

- Image Type - Filled (заполнение)
- Fill Method - Radial 360 (радиально по кругу 360)
- Fill origin -  любой (можно top/right/bottom/left)
- Clockwise - по часовой/против часовой стрелке

Меняя параметр `FillAmount` можно будет изменять размер картинки по кругу. Изменять значение можно с 0 до 1 - будет появляться, с 1 до 0 - исчезать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Останется только через скрипт обращаться к этому объекту, к этому компоненту к параметру `FillAmount` и изменять его постепенно на нужное значение.